# in C#, new class object changes original object value, but struct not

Tags: c#

something is not very clear to me while using c#, hope I can get some answers here

```
using System;

public struct SampleStruct {
    public float v;
}
public class SampleClass {
    public float v;
}
public class Program
{
    private float aaa;
    private float bbb;
    private SampleClass c111 = new SampleClass();
    private SampleClass c222 = new SampleClass();
    private SampleStruct AAA = new SampleStruct();
    private SampleStruct BBB = new SampleStruct();

    public void Main()
    {

      //test int field
      aaa = 10;
      bbb = aaa;
      bbb = 9;
      Console.WriteLine("int test: " + aaa);

      //test class
      c111 = new SampleClass { v = 10 };
      c222 = c111;
      c222.v = 9;
      Console.WriteLine("class test: " + c111.v);

      //test struct
      AAA = new SampleStruct { v = 10 };
      BBB = AAA;
      BBB.v = 9;
      Console.WriteLine("class struct: " + AAA.v);
    }
}


//output
//int test: 10
//class test: 9
//class struct: 10
```

My question is why a Class object behaviors differently than a struct here
as you can see if I change the latter object it affects to the object where it copied from

Comment: Look up value types vs reference types.

Comment: hint: an `int` is a `struct` (also known as "value type"). ([see documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32?view=net-5.0)). and follow John's advice ;)

Comment: When you assign a struct (value) object to a variable, a copy of the struct is made, so that both objects are separate. When you assign a class (reference) object to a variable, just the reference to the object is copied, so there is only one object with two references pointing to it.

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to understand that struct is a value type while class is a reference type which means that in struct the data is copied by value which means every time a new copy of data is created while in case of reference type we just have a new copy of reference pointing to same data.

When this line executes:

```
c222 = c111;
```

both `c222` and `c111` are pointing to same data or memory location. Now when the following line executes :

```
c222.v = 9;
```

both `c222` and `c111` are able to see the changed data as both are pointing to same data or memory location.

while when this line executes:

```
BBB = AAA;
```

there is new copy of the data that is in the `AAA` but changing `BBB` will not affect `AAA` as `BBB` is copied by value from `AAA` not reference.

You should go through the following to get more understanding of this:

[Value Types and Reference Types Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/value-types-and-reference-types#:%7E:text=Variables%20of%20reference%20types%20store,referenced%20by%20the%20other%20variable.)